# TypeScript Interfaces definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and writing of interfaces and I would like to know if these are equivalent:

This:

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
}

export interface UsersResponse {
  results: {
    users: {
      [userId: string]: User
    }
  }
  more: boolean
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
}

export interface userList {
    [userId: string]: User
}

export interface UsersResponse {
  results: {
    users: userList
  }
  more: boolean
}
```

everything seems to work, and I sort of stumbled upon this when i needed to use the userList interface for one of my variables. Is the second example valid?

Comment: Except for the fact that the second one exports an extra type, yes, they are equivalent. You might prefer to write `Record<string, User>` instead, since that is shorter.

Comment: I actually need the userList interface in another part of the code, I just thought writing it like the second example would be more concise if it was possibly. I'm glad it is

Comment: In that case, `export type UserList = Record<string, User>` works too. I recommend naming types in UpperCamelCase for consistency.